# How can i show two values of data from database in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I expect to join the year and the month the output like this in the table "2019-5"
The others doing fine, organizer, and workshop shows its data, the only problem is the year and the month i wanted to show.

```html
<tbody id="idTbodyWorkshop">
  <tr th:each="item : ${keyworkshop}">
    <td th:text="${item.training_name}">Workshop</td>
    <td th:text="${item.organizer}">Organizer</td>
    <td th:text="${item.training_year}" th:text="${item.training_month}">Date /*This is the 2 values i mentioned*/</td>
    <td th:text="${item.training_duration}">Duration</td>
    <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
          More <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="clDropdown" data-value="0"><a href="#">edit</a></li>
          <li class="clDropdown" data-value="1"><a href="#">delete</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: spring boot and jquery. sorry total noobs here and also new to stackoverflow

Comment: `th:text="${item.training_year}-${item.training_month}"`?

Comment: I assume this is also using Thymeleaf templating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide both the values concatenated with the `-` in a single `th:text` attribute, like this:

```
<td th:text="${item.training_year + '-' + item.training_month}">Date</td>
```

Comment: You don't need to do that at all. The browser does it for you when the element is removed from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
th:text="${item.training_year item.training_month}"
```

it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can scope your variable inside `${}` and for constant content use colon('') .

`${item.training_year + '-' + item.training_month}`